# Spam registrations even after adding domain to Mollom blacklist

Tags: users, advertising

I have a problem with spambots from itregi.com and drupaler.org that registers accounts on my clients Drupal site. I have Spamicide and Mollom installed and I have also added the domains to Molloms blacklist in the following format: 
Author e-mail   contains    itregi.com

But they still get accounts with these domains as email. 
I don't know what to do more or if I am using the blacklist wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: If Mollom module you are using is not doing what it advertises, it's a bugreport, and should be posted in module's issue queue, not here.

Comment: Yes but I am not certain that I am using it right or that it is intended to work like this. I haven´t found any documentation on it.

Comment: You are using this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom ?

Comment: Yes that is the one. I am fairly new to Drupal so I don´t know where to look for all the answers I need yet and when to post where.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot), it's a module specially designed for spambot filtering...

Comment: Thanks I think Spamicide is supposed to do the same thing as Honeypot but I will look into it.

Comment: @lovelainen yes, spamicide uses the same technique, but it's hard to predict whose implementation of it will be more effective now. It's a constant armaments race between authors and spammers.

Comment: Installed Honeypot hopefully it will help.

Comment: I'm going to be the bearer of bad news.  Honeypot will not stop this.  I have Honeypot running on my heavy traffic site and it helps a lot but I am still getting itregi.com and drupaler.org registrations.  I'm going to probably write a little custom code to block those domain names in my Drupal instance.

Comment: Oh I was afraid of this. :S Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in the last few days and every time i delete the created account by the spammer or block it, the spammer re-register again.

At my website the spammer@drupaler.org did create too many nodes using the (Forum Module).

**Solution in my case** was to use [User restrictions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions)

I am using [User restrictions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) now for 2 days without any problem and the spammer can not post any node and can not even register.

Advice: The module send an error message that the email (e.g. spammer-email@example.com) that is used to register is not allowed, may be you change this message to something tricky like (the email syntax is not correct), in case it is a human spammer not machine spammer.

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not necessarily answer the question as such but it might aid you.  If you use something like Captcha during registration (https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) it will prevent loads of the spambots to successfully register.  You can then set your permission to deny posting unless registration was completed.

Comment: Yes we use Mollom for captcha. :) But it still doesn't prevent them all sadly.

Comment: Unfortunately these are not spam bots.  They are human beings.  I've been fighting itregi.com and most recently drupaler.org registrations for over a month.  I'm going to have to resort to some custom code to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

- [BOTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha)
- [Fail2Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban)

A site we just inherited also just got hit last night. Around 11pm I got an alert mail for the account using a bit more than expected bandwidth. Quickly saw that the site was being overrun with spam. New registrations with the same (and more) domains as OP.

I blocked new user registrations and disabled new content creation permission. Then added fail2ban with a few filters to pick up the problem botnet attempts and block them and went to bed (not a critical time for this site).

Today we tweaked the fail2ban filters and also added BOTCHA. When we removed the spam accounts we also took note of the account names the botnet created.

The new Fail2Ban filters apply to three jails, one for failed login attempts by the botnet's previously created accounts (now deleted), one for BOTCHA and one for incorrect CAPTCHA (for log entries from before today when we used Honeypot).

PS: I can only guess that it's a botnet - the IPs change all the time and still hit the site now with thousands already blocked.

I prefer not using off-site services like Mollom or reCAPCHA. But BOTCHA will work with them too if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LarS for pointing me in the right direction.  I've removed the evil core hack.  Here's the code for the same functionality using hooks if it's helpful to anybody.

This code can be used in the template.php file of your theme or in a custom module, however it should be put in a custom module because it is functionality, not visuals. If you were to change your theme you would still want to keep this.
Replace THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME with your own theme or module name.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Alter the user registration form to add custom validation.
 */
function THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add a custom validate function.
  $form['#validate'][] = 'THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_user_validate_form';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Alter the user edit form to add custom validation.
 */
function THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add a custom validate function.
  $form['#validate'][] = 'THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_user_validate_form';
}

/**
 * Custom validation for the user register and edit forms.
 */
function THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_user_validate_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];

  if (!THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_user_validate_mail_not_spam($mail)) {
    form_set_error('mail', t('The e-mail address %mail is not valid.', array('%mail' => $mail)));
  }
}

/**
 * Validate an email address against known spam domains.
 *
 * @param string $mail
 *   The email address to validate.
 *
 * @return boolean
 *   Returns TRUE if the email passes validation and FALSE otherwise.
 */
function THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_user_validate_mail_not_spam($mail) {
  if (preg_match("/@tattooideas1.com/i", $mail)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  if (preg_match("/@saccatalyst.com/i", $mail)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  if (preg_match("/@cowgirljules.com/i", $mail)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  if (preg_match("/@drupaler.org/i", $mail)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please, never hack core! Instead you should try the hook system, for example see [Hook into Drupal registration and validate user info against business logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264301/hook-into-drupal-registration-and-validate-user-info-against-business-logic).

Comment: I made some tweaks to the code to adhere to Drupal coding standards and add more comments. I also added a note that this can (and should) go in a custom module instead of a theme template.php.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a custom module, I simply created a rule using the Rules module.

---

**Rules**

> +Add new rule

(call it whatever you want.  Registration Blacklist maybe?)

**Events**

> Before saving a user account
>
> After saving a new user account

**Conditions**

> Text comparison
>
> Parameter: Text: [account:mail], Matching text: drupaler.org

(Make sure it is set to "contains")

**Actions**

> Block a user
>
> Parameter: User: [account]
>
> Delete entity
>
> Parameter: Entity: [account]

---

If a person wanted to, they could setup the action to ban the IP address instead or in addition to blocking the user.

The reason for the two events is because you can't delete the account until after it's been saved.  Ideally, I wish Rules would simply kick them out and not even create an account period, but that's beyond my knowledge at this point.

If a person wanted to have some fun, they could setup a page redirect and send the bot/user to some funky webpage, ideally a redirect loop page.  For example, I setup another action rule that redirects the dupraler.org people to a page that will cause a modern browser to hang: http://www.neocodex.us/forum/topic/118146-redirectshtml-pranktroll-page/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little module to help me with this: Its not on Drupal.org at this time but it is available on GitHub here: https://github.com/coralnexus/regstop

RegStop is very straightforward to use - though it is fresh - like 2 days old ;-)

If anyone has suggestions for improvements, let me know.

Thanks, Derek

Answer (score 0):

Not to step on Derek's toes, but I was also working on a module for the very same issue. I did not see this until now though, but do plan on adding even more validation to the user registration form down the road.

It started as a project for a client of mine, he was getting hammered with at least a dozen human spam registrations a day from the drupaler.org and yandex.com e-mail domains. Put this together for him this week, so it is pretty young as well.

[Registration validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_validation)